# Scala Helloworld program issue

Tags: scala

What is wrong with this code?

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Error output:

```
 }

 <console>:1: error: eof expected but '}' found.
}
^
```

Comment: Is the above code all in your file?  Or is some of that output from trying to run?

Comment: @childofsoong, yes, I re-post and re-format my code and error output, and appreciate if you could take a look. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointed out the extra brace that you need to remove below

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}


 } //You have to remove this extra brace
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, vote up, and I have re-post and re-format my code and error output, but I do not think I have an extra `}`, and appreciate if you could take a look. :)

Comment: I used that part of code and compiled it successfully.

And based on the compiler error, you really do have an extra `}`

Comment: Hi Adrian, I find the issue is the `"` is unicode (I copy it from a web page), but the error output is a bit confusing. I rewrite `"` and it works for me now. Thanks for all the help and mark your reply as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Valid (and syntactically shorter) is also to define a *main* object that extends trait `App`,

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello world" + args.mkString(" "))
}
```